# Basic BI questions of calculating formulas from raw data on 15-min and 1-hr intervals?

Tags: sql, t-sql, ssas, business-intelligence, bids

I'm new to BI and I'm working on a project that (I believe) can help me gain experience with this technology. The formula I'm working on now is really the simplest one.

We have 15-minute data that has tons of counters. I'm currently storing in a table called [Counter15MinCityDataRaw], like so:

```
Id      City    Date        Hour    Minute  KpiValue    Counters        InsertDate
108823  Miami   20140930    9       0       100.00      Auto            2014-09-30 12:17:07.580    
108824  NYC     20140930    9       0       0.50        Added           2014-09-30 12:17:07.580    
108825  Vegas   20140930    9       0       12.00       Att             2014-09-30 12:17:07.580    
108826  Miami   20140930    9       0       40.00       Man             2014-09-30 12:17:07.580    
108823  Miami   20140930    9       15      100.00      Auto            2014-09-30 12:17:07.580    
108824  NYC     20140930    9       15      0.50        Added           2014-09-30 12:17:07.580    
108825  Vegas   20140930    9       15      12.00       Att             2014-09-30 12:17:07.580    
108826  Miami   20140930    9       15      40.00       Man             2014-09-30 12:17:07.580
```

This is the raw data. The first formula I'll be working on is [TotalPopulation], that looks like this: [TotalPopulation] = (Q + (*Auto*+*Man*)) / 400. **Q** equals the Number of quarters being processed (ie. **Q** = 1 for 15-minute interval, **Q** = 4 for 1-hr interval)

So my intial requirements is to create a report that displays the [TotalPopulation] for each *City* in 15-min and 1-hr intervals.

So I already created both [DimDate] and [DimCity] tables, although I don't think they're going to help when I calculate the 15-minute intervals and the 1-hr intervals. Also, can I use the raw data *as is* for the fact table, or would I need to group the data by *city* and *counter* (in this case *Auto* and *Man*)  into a new fact table?

So my question is: do I need a dimension table for the 15-minute intervals and 1-hour intervals? How would my Fact table look like? Would I also need a dim table for the **Q** variable?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could create a dimension "Interval", containing just the two values (15, 0). Link this dimension to your Facttable Minute Field.

Use the dimension to filter the result in the front-end.

Answer (score 0):

Use separate dimension tables for date and intervals. Date dimension would become too big if you include intervals, even 15 min intervals.

Don't aggregate data in fact table, always use granular date to be able to satisfy all the analytics needs : you can always aggregate granular data but the reverse is not true. Then you could possibly use aggregates to improve performance, or OLAP aggregations.

Last, I think you should not use a dim for Q, because Q refers to different aggregation levels of the interval value, so you would end with rows in fact table having different levels of aggregation. It is a very bad practice to mix diffent granularities in the fact table, as it is error prone for report developers when requesting data and also because the data would quickly become hard to maintain.

These are indeed classic BI questions, and are documented in-depth in Kimball's books or papers.